# How to extract REST API parameters from DataFlow template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-apis-explorer

I want to trigger Data Flow with Cloud Function in Google Cloud Platform.

In Cloud Function, I'm calling the [API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch) like this with Python:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)

request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(
    projectId=projectId, gcsPath=srcDataFlowTemplate, location='us', body={
        'jobName': jobName,
        'parameters': parameters,
        'environment':environment
    }
)

response = request.execute()
```

and this is pipe in Data Flow template which I am launching:

```
(p
   | 'Create PCollection' >> beam.Create(inputFile)
   | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText(skip_header_lines=1)
   | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.WriteToBigQuery (table,
                project=projectId,
                dataset=dataset,
                schema=schema,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
    )
)
```

In Data Flow template - is it possible to extract this 'inputFile' which is stored in body of the request under parameters property and projectId from API call?

Comment: Can you list the variable that you want? and why? I can easily get some, others are harder and I want to be sure before digging into!

Comment: I have updated my question. I am new to this environment so I don't know if this is possible. I basically want to extract this {projectId} in DataFlow template after I make this call: https:// dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{projectId}/templates:launch

Answer (score 2):

When you run a job on Dataflow with Beam framework, you use the DataflowRunner. When you create the pipeline, you create it with "options" object.

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
```

[This object contains basic parameters](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/), such as the projectId, and you can extend it to add your own pipeline parameters.